# Why client.UploadFile not available in tlsharp

Tags: c#, client, telegram

I use TLSharp v-1.0.0.0
I want send photo and file by this but client.UploadFile not available!

my code is:

```
var fileResult = (TLInputFile) await client.UploadFile(
                                        filename, 
                                        new StreamReader(directory));
```

Here is what I see in the [IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1butn.jpg).

Comment: Probably going to need more code to figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: Grammar; noise reduction; layout.

Answer (score -1):

missing namespace:
using TLSharp.Core.Utils;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).